# Why jQuery data won't work with append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am appending data from server to an unordered list, however setting `data-id` attribute with `data()` doesn't work, but `attr()` does.

---

### When using `data()`:

Appends `<li>Home</li>`

```js
$('#menu').append($('<li>').text("Home").data('id', 5));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
</ul>
```

### When using `attr()`:

Appends `<li data-id="5">Home</li>`

```js
$('#menu').append($('<li>').text("Home").attr('data-id', 5));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu">
</ul>
```

I know I could append it like so, but prefer the first option.

```
$('#menu').append('<li data-id="5">Home</li>');
```

Comment: the jQuery data api, uses an internal data structure to store the data, so that will not get updated the mark as attribute

Comment: why do you want the attribute to be updated?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.data()` method will read the data-* attribute as a secondary function. But what it first tries to do is read the data from jQuery's internal cache as a key-value pair (attached to the element).

The main takeaway is, it doesn't work the other way around. I.e. `.data()` will not put attributes on an element. It will just store data in jQuery's internal cache to be associated with that element.

Comment: Yes that's correct. It will first check if data has been set before, and if it has it will read it, irrespective of the html element's attributes. If it so happens that data was never called, it will try to read the associated data-* attribute.

Comment: Accidentally deleted the first comment, thanks for the explanation, makes total sense now.